# Linear Regression parameters are not calculated correctly

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient-descent

My gradient descent does not give the correct values for the model coefficients.

Here is my code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("Advertising.csv")
tv_ad = np.array(data.loc[:, "TV"]) 
sales = np.array(data.loc[:, "sales"]) 

#The first 5 datapoints are these:

for i in range(5):
    print(f"(x^({i}), y^({i})) = ({tv_ad[i]}, {sales[i]})")

"""Output: 
(x^(0), y^(0)) = (230.1, 22.1)
(x^(1), y^(1)) = (44.5, 10.4)
(x^(2), y^(2)) = (17.2, 9.3)
(x^(3), y^(3)) = (151.5, 18.5)
(x^(4), y^(4)) = (180.8, 12.9)"""


#This is the cost function:

def compute_cost_func(x, y, w, b):
    
    count = x.shape[0]
    cost_sum = 0
    
    for i in range(count):
        x_i, y_i = x[i], y[i]
        cost_sum += (w * x_i + b - y_i) ** 2
    
    j_wb = cost_sum / (2 * count)
    
    return j_wb

#This is the gradient calculator:

def compute_gradient(x, y, w, b):
    
    count = x.shape[0]
    dj_dw, dj_db = 0, 0
    
    for i in range(count):
        x_i, y_i = x[i], y[i]
        func_w = ((w * x_i + b) - y_i) * x_i
        func_b = (w * x_i + b) - y_i
        
        dj_dw += func_w
        dj_db += func_b
    
    dj_dw = dj_dw / count
    dj_db = dj_db / count
    
    return dj_dw, dj_db

#This is the gradient descent function:

def gradient_descent(x, y, w_in, b_in, alpha, num_iter, cost_func, gradient_func):

    j_history = []
    p_history = []
    b = b_in
    w = w_in
    
    for i in range(num_iter):
        
        dj_dw, dj_db = gradient_func(x, y, w, b)
        
        w = w - alpha * dj_dw
        b = b - alpha * dj_db
        
        if i < 100000:
            j_history.append(cost_func(x, y, w, b))
            p_history.append([w, b])
            
        if i % math.ceil(num_iter / 10) == 0:
            print(f"Iteration {i:4}: Cost {j_history[-1]:0.2e} ",
                  f"dj_dw: {dj_dw: 0.3e}, dj_db: {dj_db: 0.3e}  ",
                  f"w: {w: 0.3e}, b:{b: 0.5e}")
    
    return w, b, j_history, p_history

#When I run the code, at the end it gives w and b but they are not correct.

w_init = 0
b_init = 0

iterations = 10000
tmp_alpha = 1.0e-5

w_final, b_final, j_hist, p_hist = gradient_descent(tv_ad, sales, w_init, b_init, tmp_alpha, iterations,
                                                    compute_cost_func, compute_gradient)
print(f"(w,b) found by gradient descent: ({w_final:8.4f},{b_final:8.4f})")

"""
Output:
Iteration    0: Cost 6.22e+01  dj_dw: -2.411e+03, dj_db: -1.402e+01   w:  2.411e-02, b: 1.40225e-04
Iteration 1000: Cost 1.15e+01  dj_dw:  9.022e-03, dj_db: -1.777e+00   w:  8.316e-02, b: 1.82292e-02
Iteration 2000: Cost 1.15e+01  dj_dw:  8.999e-03, dj_db: -1.772e+00   w:  8.307e-02, b: 3.59728e-02
Iteration 3000: Cost 1.14e+01  dj_dw:  8.976e-03, dj_db: -1.768e+00   w:  8.298e-02, b: 5.36715e-02
Iteration 4000: Cost 1.14e+01  dj_dw:  8.954e-03, dj_db: -1.763e+00   w:  8.289e-02, b: 7.13254e-02
Iteration 5000: Cost 1.14e+01  dj_dw:  8.931e-03, dj_db: -1.759e+00   w:  8.280e-02, b: 8.89347e-02
Iteration 6000: Cost 1.13e+01  dj_dw:  8.909e-03, dj_db: -1.754e+00   w:  8.271e-02, b: 1.06499e-01
Iteration 7000: Cost 1.13e+01  dj_dw:  8.886e-03, dj_db: -1.750e+00   w:  8.262e-02, b: 1.24020e-01
Iteration 8000: Cost 1.13e+01  dj_dw:  8.864e-03, dj_db: -1.745e+00   w:  8.253e-02, b: 1.41496e-01
Iteration 9000: Cost 1.12e+01  dj_dw:  8.841e-03, dj_db: -1.741e+00   w:  8.244e-02, b: 1.58928e-01
(w,b) found by gradient descent: (  0.0824,  0.1763)"""
```

The given w and b are w = 0.0824, b = 0.1763. And in the scatterplot the graph is like this:
[image]

Instead, when I compute the model with statsmodel the w and b values are w = 0.0475 and b = 7.0326. And they looks like more correct. The graph of this model is this.

[image]

I wonder what it wrong with my gradient descent function. I know my question is long but I am really curious about it.

I tried it with a smaller dataset, it worked but I don't know whether something is wrong with my gradient descent or it is about the dataset.

Comment: Gradient descent is not the same as a classical linear regression, even if you want to achieve the same outcome. Gradient descent might find local minima, which can be quite different from the global minima and therefore the optimal solution. I think your code should be correct.  You can additionally test, whether your gradient descent algorithm will find the "true" solution starting from parameters, that are rather close to the "true" solution.

Comment: But this is a 1-variable linear regression, not a multi-variable LR. So, it only has 1 local minimum and that is global minimum.

Comment: https://ozzieliu.com/assets/img/gradientdescent.png like this